# Insert data to MS Access DB through JDBC-ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I tried to insert some data from java to my database (ms.access) but when I click button nothing add to database. here is the code:

```
private void EmpButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {        
    String name,sex,email,username,password;
    name = tfName.getText();
    sex=(String) cbSex.getSelectedItem();
    email=tfEmail.getText();
    username=tfUser.getText();

    try{
        String url;
        url = "jdbc:odbc:mydata";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"",""); 
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO EmployeeLogin " + "VALUES (name, email, sex, username)");
        conn.close();
    }catch (SQLException sqlException){} 
}
```

what wrong with that code?

Comment: It is NOT JButton doing the insert for you.  Have you been able to do it with a most simple console program?  And, you should NOT catch and ignore the exception.  Most probably there are exception happening but now you missed them all

Comment: first, display the exception somewhere, so that you know when problem happens, and what is the problem

Comment: put sqlException.printStackTrace(); inside catch block and also put some System.out statements in try block to see if it is coming in your code or not

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the way to do it...

```
String sex=(String) cbSex.getSelectedItem();
    try{
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:mydata";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO CustomerLogin(Name, Email, Sex, Username, Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";     
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, tfName.getText());
pst.setString(2, tfEmail.getText());
pst.setString(3, sex);
pst.setString(4, tfUser.getText());
pst.setString(5, pfPassword.getText());

pst.execute();
tfName.setText("");
tfEmail.setText("");
tfUser.setText("");
pfPassword.setText("");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Succed Create Account! You can now return to Login Page");


        }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); }
```

Comment: add PreparedStatement pst=null; in public class

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is :

```
stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO EmployeeLogin " + "VALUES (name, email, sex, username)");
```

write like :

```
stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO EmployeeLogin VALUES ("+name+", "+email+", "+sex+", "+username+")");
```

Comment: still not see in database